# Hide navigation and status bar for cordova android/ios app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I want to hide status and navigation bar in my cordova android/ios app.
I was using cordova status bar plugin to hide status bar but it doesn't hide status bar in splash screen and when i used @android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen it hides the status bar completely but when i click on input field then input field hide behind the keyboard that's opened when user click on input field and user is unable to see what is being written on input field.

And for navigation bar i was using cordova navigation bar plugin it hides the navigation bar but when user clicks on screen it shows navigation bar
I want if user swipe upwards than only navigation bar will appear.

Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For ANdroid, you have to look into immerse fullscreen mode. That is the only way to hide the navbar